# How to extract field value from REST response (json or xml) with Rest Assured?

Tags: rest-assured

I want to extract value from string typed REST response (json or xml). I tried the following code:

```
final Response response = new ResponseBuilder().setContentType("application/json").setStatusCode(200).setBody("{\"message\":\"hello\"}").build();
Object object = response.path("message");
System.out.println(object);
```

But it compains

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getObjectMapperConfig() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at io.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.jsonPath(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:358)
```

The root cause is RestAssuredConfig object is null in RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl

So, How can I construct Response object from raw string response correctly without get() or post() since I already have string response?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl response = new RestAssuredResponseImpl();
response.setConfig(RestAssuredConfig.config());
response.setRpr(new ResponseParserRegistrar());
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setStatusCode(200);
response.setContent("{\"message\":\"hello\"}");
Object message = response.path("message");
System.out.println(message);
```